# How to install bson npm package on a Windows 8.1 OS?

Tags: node.js, npm, bson

When trying to `npm install -g bson` on my Windows 8.1 OS, it fails with the following message:

[image: npm error]

When trying to see what's wrong in the NPM debug log, I've got only that:

[image: npm debug log]

I've tried to search around and all I could find was:

- is node and system32 in the PATH ? (yes they are)
- run the command line as administrator (already is)
- is Python and Visual C++ 10 installed ? (yes they are)

And that's it. Does anybody have a clue of what I can do to make this works (the goal here is to install mongoose...) ?